# Collecting FAQ on LaTeX in this site into a recipe book that is collaberatively developed by us

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

There are many questions that can be regarded as FAQ as follows:

1. How to adjust column separation in two-column page?
2. How to break column in multiple-column page?
3. How to enlarge the list indentation?
4. How to make list start from zero?
5. How to put annotations on the existing picture?
6. How to include programming code on the PDF output?
7. How to convert PDF to EPS?

I think that they should be collected and transformed into a single free LaTeX recipe book that may be collaboratively managed by our volunteers.

### Advantages

1. Well-phrased title on the book make ones easily find what they are looking for. So it will reduce the chance of duplicate questions.
2. If the duplicate question happens, we can also easily give the questioner a reference to the available solution.
3. If there are volunteers with good English grammar, the sentence in the book can be phrased without ambiguities.
4. Free!

### Disadvantages

1. Damage the economy of people selling commercial book.

I haven't used any collaboration system that are available on the web. Maybe someone can give me a suggestion how to start this idea.

I hope my idea is useful.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq (though it doesn't seem to work very well).

Comment: I just found a cool site that collects Q/A from SE/SO, see [FAQoverflow](http://www.faqoverflow.com/). :-)

Answer (score 10):

Regarding real FAQs on our site, we have to identify them. Votes mark great questions, but not the frequency of occurence. Useful for spotting FAQs:

- Questions closed as a duplicate
- The StackExchange Data Explorer:

  - [Possible duplicates v1](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/s/1207/possible-duplicates)
  - [Possible duplicates v1](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/s/1449/possible-duplicates)
- The sidebar with [linked questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-linked-posts/) which includes duplicates as it's bi-directional

A question without a duplicate doesn't qualify as a FAQ (yet).

Here are already existing FAQ collections, from our [online resources](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162/what-are-other-good-resources-on-line-for-information-about-tex-latex-and-friend/1621#1621) post:

- [UK TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/faq): FAQ of the UK TeX Users Group, maintened by Robin Fairbairns
- [The Visual LaTeX FAQ](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/visualFAQ): formatting samples available through a hyperlink interface
- [MacTeX FAQ](http://tug.org/mactex/faq/): Mac OS X specific questions and answers
- [AMS author FAQ](http://www.ams.org/authors/author-faq.html): FAQ for AMS authors dealing with AMS-LaTeX and `amsmath` but also with LaTeX in general
- [de-tex-faq](http://www.dante.de/faq/de-tex-faq/): FAQ of the German TeX user group DANTE e.V.
- [Picture FAQ](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/l2picfaq/german): How to Include Pictures, in German

These are possible competitors to the intention of this question, however I would encourage supporting existing community FAQ projects. Our site can provide good contributions. Our content is cc-wiki licensed, proper attribution on other sites leads users to our site.

Comment: Is there some way to count the number of links to a TeX.SX question from other TeX.SX questions?  That would pick up things like "Have you read question X?" and "I followed the answers in question X and encountered the following problem ..." which both indicate "nearness" of questions.

Comment: the "amsmath faq" was obliterated when ams combined all faq information in a single database.  (a serious loss, if you ask me.)  i've tried to incorporate the material into the ams author faq, but with not totally satisfying results.  anyhow, i've removed that item from your answer.

Answer (score 3):

### How can I deal with underfull or overful hboxes and vboxes?

- [What are underfull hboxes and vboxes and how can I get rid of them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138/what-are-underfull-hboxes-and-vboxes-and-how-can-i-get-rid-of-them)
- [What does “overfull hbox” mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35/what-does-overfull-hbox-mean)
- [Overfull \hbox Warning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6237/overfull-hbox-warning)
- [How to suppress overfull hbox warnings up to some maximum?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13715/how-to-suppress-overfull-hbox-warnings-up-to-some-maximum)

Answer (score 3):

### How can I include a raster image in LaTeX getting the best possible quality?

- [How do I insert an image in LaTeX so it looks good on print?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165/how-do-i-insert-an-image-in-latex-so-it-looks-good-on-print)
- [My pixel perfect picture gets blurry when compiled in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10975/my-pixel-perfect-picture-gets-blurry-when-compiled-in-latex)
- [Included PNG appears blurry in PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1162/included-png-appears-blurry-in-pdf)
- [How to embed screenshots properly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/how-to-embed-screenshots-properly)
- [How do you deal with fixed resolution screenshots? (e.g. GUI screenshots)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4291/how-do-you-deal-with-fixed-resolution-screenshots-e-g-gui-screenshots)
- [Losing resolution when using \includegraphics to import JPEG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17897/losing-resolution-when-using-includegraphics-to-import-jpeg)
- [How to obtain clear printed graphics with PCTeX v6](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17899/how-to-obtain-clear-printed-graphics-with-pctex-v6)
- [Blurry images in document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17899/how-to-obtain-clear-printed-graphics-with-pctex-v6) (closed)

Answer (score 3):

### How to install a package?

(I'm in a rush but heres [relevant search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=install))

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Community Wiki post for a start, collecting frequently asked questions to one topic and listing duplicates. Feel free to edit if you like. Let's see how it works out, it should give us some material to experiment.

I'd suggest: vote for FAQs which you mean are very frequent, add another answer for another FAQ (CW).

### How can I limit or even suppress floating of figures or tables?

- [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)
- [Force figure placement in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text)
- [How do I ensure that figures appear in the section they're associated with?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279/how-do-i-ensure-that-figures-appear-in-the-section-theyre-associated-with)
- [How to avoid splitting tables between sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/how-to-avoid-splitting-tables-between-sections)
- [Tables and sections get misplaced](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15507/tables-and-sections-get-misplaced)
- [How can I force figure to stay in section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24588/how-can-i-force-figure-to-stay-in-section) (closed)
- [How to bind figure (table) to a section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20376/how-to-bind-figure-table-to-a-section) (closed)
- [Positioning figures in specific places](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16518/positioning-figures-in-specific-places) (closed)
- [\subsubsection <— How do I ensure that figures appear in the section they're associated with?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14151/subsubsection-how-do-i-ensure-that-figures-appear-in-the-section-theyre-ass) (closed)
- [How can I inhibit LaTeX to float a table across a section boundary?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11791/how-can-i-inhibit-latex-to-float-a-table-across-a-section-boundary) (closed)
- [How can I restrict the placement of images?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20602/how-can-i-restrict-the-placement-of-images) (closed)

Answer (score 2):

### How can I typeset source code of any programming language with syntax higlighting?

- [Syntax Coloring in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/867/syntax-coloring-in-latex)
- [How best to include programming source code in LaTeX documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2037/how-best-to-include-programming-source-code-in-latex-documents)
- [How display LaTeX code in LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4095/how-display-latex-code-in-latex-document)
- [Package for displaying source code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7614/package-for-displaying-source-code) (closed)